# Using custom icons for multiple locations with Folium and Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, leaflet, geolocation, folium

I am trying to iterate over a pandas dataframe to plot multiple geolocations on a Folium map using custom icons as markers instead of the default one.

First I create a pandas dataframe as follows:

```
# dependencies
import folium 
import pandas as pd 

from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive/')

    # create dummy data
    df = {'Lat': [22.50, 63.21, -13.21, 33.46],
                'Lon': [43.91, -22.22, 77.11, 22.11],
                'Color': ['red', 'yellow', 'orange', 'blue']
              }
      
# create dataframe
data = pd.DataFrame(df)
```

I then create a world map with a zoom factor of 2:

```
world = folium.Map(
    zoom_start=2
    )
```

I can plot the locations by iterating over the dataframe rows as follows:

```
x = data[['Lat', 'Lon', 'Color']].copy()

    for index, row in x.iterrows():
        folium.Marker([row['Lat'], row['Lon']],
                            popup=row['Color'],
                            icon=folium.Icon(color="red", icon="info-sign")
                           ).add_to(world)
    
    world
```

This produces the following graphic:

[image]

In order to use a custom icon I need to use `folium.features.CustomIcon` and state the image path as a location on my Google Drive where the image is stored.

```
pushpin = folium.features.CustomIcon('/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/pushpin.png', icon_size=(30,30))
```

I can use this on the map in one stated location as follows:

```
world = folium.Map(
    zoom_start=2
    )

folium.Marker([40.743720, -73.822030], icon=pushpin).add_to(world)
world
```

Which produces the following graphic
[image]

However, when I try to use the custom icon in the iteration, it does not seem to work and only plots the first coordinate pair with the default marker.

```
pushpin = folium.features.CustomIcon('/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/pushpin.png', icon_size=(30,30))
    
    world = folium.Map(
    zoom_start=2
    )
            
    x = data[['Lat', 'Lon', 'Color']].copy()
            
    for index, row in x.iterrows():
         folium.Marker([row['Lat'], row['Lon']],
                                    icon=pushpin,
                                    popup=row['Color'],
                                   ).add_to(world)
            
            
            world
```

As pictured:

[image]

My expectation is for all 4 positions to be plotted with the pushpin marker.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the only way to do this is to place the custom icon call within the for loop so it initialises for each iterration, eg:

```
    world = folium.Map(
    zoom_start=2
    )
            
    x = data[['Lat', 'Lon', 'Color']].copy()
            
    for index, row in x.iterrows():
         pushpin = folium.features.CustomIcon('/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/pushpin.png', icon_size=(30,30))
         folium.Marker([row['Lat'], row['Lon']],
                                    icon=pushpin,
                                    popup=row['Color'],
                                   ).add_to(world)
            
            
    world
```

This produces the following graphic:

[image]

Comment: perfectly works!

Comment: Glad to hear it, Hissaan!